# How to name Pandas Dataframe Columns automatically?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I have a Pandas dataframe `df` with **102** columns. Each column is named differently, say `A, B, C` etc. to give the original dataframe following structure

```
         Column A.    Column B.  Column C.   ....
Row 1.    
Row 2.
---
Row n
```

I would like to change the columns names from `A, B, C` etc. to `F1, F2, F3, ...., F102`. I tried using df.columns but wasn't successful in renaming them this way. Any simple way to automatically rename all column names to `F1 to F102` automatically, insteading of renaming each column name individually?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
df.columns=["F"+str(i) for i in range(1, 103)]
```

---

*Note:*

Instead of a “magic” number `103` you may use the *calculated number of columns* (+ 1), e.g.

- `len(df.columns) + 1`, or
- `df.shape[1] + 1`.

(Thanks to [ALollz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4333359/alollz) for this tip in his comment.)

Comment: Might be worth doing `["F"+str(i+1) for i in range(df.shape[1])]` that way you never need to explicitly write the number of columns.

Comment: @ALollz, you're right, thanks, I'll probably add something as it into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to convert it to a pair of lists, and convert the column names list to the index of a loop:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Column A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], 'Column B': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1], 'Column c': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]}
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
cols = list(dataFrame.columns.values)                 #convert original dataframe into a list containing the values for column name
index = 1                                             #start at 1
for column in cols:
    cols[index-1] = "F"+str(index)                    #rename the column name based on index
    index += 1                                             #add one to index
vals = dataFrame.values.tolist()                      #get the values for the rows
newDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(vals,   columns=cols)     #create a new dataframe containing the new column names and values from rows
print(newDataFrame)
```

Output:

```
   F1  F2  F3
0   1   1   1
1   2   2   2
2   3   3   3
3   4   4   4
4   5   5   5
5   4   4   4
6   3   3   3
7   2   2   2
8   1   1   1
```