# Replace column values in large Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a large input file of numerical data (22000) columns and at the moment when I use
`df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file)`, it uses the first line of numbers as the column values.

Is there any way to replace the column value with random variables or load the data in a way that the first line is not used as a column name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas read in table without headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287224/pandas-read-in-table-without-headers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the parameter `header=None`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file, header=None)
```

Then column names will be `0`, `1`, `2`, ..., `21999`, and *all* rows in your CSV-file will be treated as *data* rows.

If you are not satisfied with those automatically assigned column names, you may change them as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60461259/7023590) of the question “[How to name Pandas Dataframe Columns automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60461198/7023590)”

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.read_csv("path_to_file", header=0)`.

If you also want to assign names to the columns you can pass a list in the `names` parameter of pd.read_csv.