# How to create column names in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have exported the gold price data from the brokers. the file has no column names like this

2014.02.13,00:00,1291.00,1302.90,1286.20,1302.30,41906
2014.02.14,00:00,1301.80,1321.20,1299.80,1318.70,46244
2014.02.17,00:00,1318.20,1329.80,1318.10,1328.60,26811
2014.02.18,00:00,1328.60,1332.10,1312.60,1321.40,46226

I read csv to pandas dataframe and it take the first row to be the column names. I am curious how can I set the column names and still have all the data

Thank you

Comment: Related - add column names dynamically with an expression https://stackoverflow.com/a/60461259/495455

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you don't have a header in the CSV, you can instruct Pandas to ignore it using the `header` parameter

```
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None)
```

to manually assign column names to the DataFrame, you may use

```
df.columns = ["col1", "col2", ...]
```

Encourage you to go through the [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) documentation to learn more about the options it provides.